# XML parsing in Android, IXMLDOMDocument

Tags: android, xml, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a problem with parsing XML.
I managed to get into "TXMLDocument" but it does not work on **Android**.

How to get field values?
I need to get 9240-221
I need the value: "9240-221"

I did not find in Google how to do it (also did not find a manual on how to work with IXMLDOMDocument).

Code:

```
uses ComObj, MSXML;


procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  xml: IXMLDOMDocument;
  node: IXMLDomNode;
  nodes_row, nodes_se: IXMLDomNodeList;
  i, j: Integer;
  url: string;
begin

  // put url or file name
  //url := 'https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.xml?prox=32.791288%2C-17.045887&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=8&app_id=ZHsaRDKOhKQKjKOba0cS&app_code=RPlNCmcST6RICWUMk2OzYQ';

  xml := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument;
  xml.async := False;
  //xml.load(url); // or use loadXML to load XML document using a supplied string
  xml.loadXML
   (
    '<ns2:Search xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Search/4">'+
    '<Response>'+
    '<MetaInfo>...</MetaInfo>'+
    '<View xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:SearchResultsViewType"> '+
    '<ViewId>0</ViewId>'+
    '<Result>'+
    '<Relevance>1.0</Relevance>'+
    '<Distance>-1996.0</Distance>'+
    '<Direction>358.6</Direction>'+
    '<MatchLevel>city</MatchLevel>'+
    '<MatchQuality>...</MatchQuality>'+
    '<Location>'+
    '<LocationId>NT_yT.xGXLRj-bHQLe8aMmP2A</LocationId>'+
    '<LocationType>area</LocationType>'+
    '<DisplayPosition>...</DisplayPosition>'+
    '<MapView>...</MapView>'+
    '<Address>'+
    '<Label>São Vicente, Portugal</Label>'+
    '<Country>PRT</Country>'+
    '<County>Ilha da Madeira</County>'+
    '<City>São Vicente</City>'+
    '<PostalCode>9240-221</PostalCode> '+
    '<AdditionalData key="CountryName">Portugal</AdditionalData>'+
    '<AdditionalData key="CountyName">Ilha da Madeira</AdditionalData>'+
    '</Address>'+
    '<MapReference>...</MapReference>'+
    '</Location> '+
    '</Result>'+
    '</View>'+
    '</Response>'+
    '</ns2:Search>'
  );

  if xml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('XML Load error:' + xml.parseError.reason);


  nodes_row := xml.selectNodes('/ns2');
  for i := 0 to nodes_row.length - 1 do
  begin
    node := nodes_row.item[i];
    showmessage('phrase=' + node.selectSingleNode('ViewId').text);
    nodes_se := node.selectNodes('.....');
    for j := 0 to nodes_se.length - 1 do
    begin
      node := nodes_se.item[j];
    end;
    showmessage('--------------');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: IXMLDOMDocument is an Interface of a Windows XML Parser object (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd892951(v=vs.85).aspx).  Why are you expecting to use it on Android?

Comment: In "Embarcadero RadStudio 10.1Berlin - Delphi" when compiling for windows I can get "PostalCode" using "TXMLDocument", but on Android when doing the
"X: = TXMLDocument.Create (self); In runtime it gives an error and I can not get the value.
So I'm trying to figure out another way to get it.

Comment: @MartynA: OmniXML vendor is cross platform.

Comment: @whosrdaddy:  Sure, I was commenting on the reference to IXMLDOMDocument in light of `MSXML` being in the Uses clause of the code (not to mention `ComObj`).

Comment: @MartynA, Oh I see now, didn't look at the code, he mentioned TXmlDocument in the question :)

Comment: It does not matter how to get this value or which library to use. What was important was to help get the "PostalCode" from XML with in delphi on to Android?

Comment: Use TXmlDocument with DefaultVendor set to "OmniXml". Look at the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Document_Object_Model)

Comment: @JoãoRodrigues: see my updated answer

Comment: I switched to "OmniXml" and it still does not work.

Comment: Did you try my code sample on Android? if yes, what error do you get?

Comment: I'll try in Android and then I'll give you an answer.

Comment: Please make sure that you use my exact code sample (copy/paste), I verified on windows (which works), but I can't verify on Android

Comment: I can't see how you could possibly see `uses MSXML` and `CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')` and think they would work on Android. I mean, seriously - learn to actually **read** and **understand** the code you copy and paste before just blindly trying to use it.

Comment: @JoãoRodrigues: did you get it to work or not??

Comment: Some feedback would be welcome, dont bite the hand that feeds you...

Comment: I tested the TXMLDocument with the DOMVendor defined to work with OmniXM, as you said.

Xml.DOMVendor: = GetDOMVendor ('Omni XML');

It works fine, thank you very much @whosrdaddy

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cross platform support for XML documents, you can use `TXmlDocument` with the vendor set to `OmniXML`. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Document_Object_Model) (emphasis mine):

> **MSXML**  : Fastest of the built-in RAD Studio XML vendors. Windows only.
>   Default. For cross-platform support, you must choose a different XML
>   vendor. If you do not specify a different XML vendor, your application
>   does not have XML support on other platforms than Windows, and you see
>   a run-time exception when you run your application in other platforms.
>
> **OmniXML** : Much faster than ADOM, but slightly slower than MSXML.
>   **Cross-platform**.
>
> **ADOM** : Slower than the other built-in RAD Studio XML vendors.
>   **Cross-platform**.

Here is a full blown example for a solution that uses OmniXML and that works on all platforms (you need at least Delphi XE7 for this):

```
unit FrmMain;

interface

uses
  Xml.Xmldom,
  Xml.Omnixmldom,
  Xml.Xmldoc,
  Xml.Xmlintf,
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function selectNode(xnRoot: IXmlNode; const nodePath: WideString): IXmlNode;
var
  intfSelect : IDomNodeSelect;
  dnResult : IDomNode;
  intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  doc: TXmlDocument;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(xnRoot) or not Supports(xnRoot.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
    Exit;
  dnResult := intfSelect.selectNode(nodePath);
  if Assigned(dnResult) then
  begin
    if Supports(xnRoot.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
      doc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
    else
      doc := nil;
    Result := TXmlNode.Create(dnResult, nil, doc);
  end;
end;

function XPathQuery(Doc : IXMLDocument; Query : String) : String;

var
 Node : IXMLNode;

begin
 Result := '';
 Node := SelectNode(Doc.DocumentElement, Query);
 if Assigned(Node) then
  Result := Node.Text
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  Xml: IXMLDocument;
  Str : String;

begin
 DefaultDOMVendor := sOmniXmlVendor;
 Xml := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
 Xml.LoadFromXML
   (
    '<ns2:Search xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Search/4">'+
    '<Response>'+
    '<MetaInfo>...</MetaInfo>'+
    '<View xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:SearchResultsViewType"> '+
    '<ViewId>0</ViewId>'+
    '<Result>'+
    '<Relevance>1.0</Relevance>'+
    '<Distance>-1996.0</Distance>'+
    '<Direction>358.6</Direction>'+
    '<MatchLevel>city</MatchLevel>'+
    '<MatchQuality>...</MatchQuality>'+
    '<Location>'+
    '<LocationId>NT_yT.xGXLRj-bHQLe8aMmP2A</LocationId>'+
    '<LocationType>area</LocationType>'+
    '<DisplayPosition>...</DisplayPosition>'+
    '<MapView>...</MapView>'+
    '<Address>'+
    '<Label>São Vicente, Portugal</Label>'+
    '<Country>PRT</Country>'+
    '<County>Ilha da Madeira</County>'+
    '<City>São Vicente</City>'+
    '<PostalCode>9240-221</PostalCode> '+
    '<AdditionalData key="CountryName">Portugal</AdditionalData>'+
    '<AdditionalData key="CountyName">Ilha da Madeira</AdditionalData>'+
    '</Address>'+
    '<MapReference>...</MapReference>'+
    '</Location> '+
    '</Result>'+
    '</View>'+
    '</Response>'+
    '</ns2:Search>'
  );
  Str := XPathQuery(Xml, '//PostalCode');
  ShowMessage(Str);
end;

end.
```

Comment: I defined the TXMLDocument with you spoke.
Set DOMVendor to work with OmniXML.

Xml: = TXMLDocument.Create (nil);
Xml.DOMVendor := GetDOMVendor ('Omni XML');

It works fine, thank you very much.
Thank you again and sorry for the long delay in response.